# Cake PHP always return 0 $this->Layout->boolYesNo($enquiry['Enquiry']['read']

Tags: php, cakephp

This value `$enquiry['Enquiry']['read']` return 1 but in view file the status saying no ..i have print the value it display 1 ..

```
echo $this->Html->link($this->Layout->boolYesNo($enquiry['Enquiry']['read']), array('controller' => 'enquiries', 'action' => 'toggle_status', $enquiry['Enquiry']['id']), array('escape' => false));
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking - you need to explain in a way that doesn't involve guessing what you're doing and what the rest of your application code looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$answer = ($enquiry['Enquiry']['read'] == 0) ? 'No' : 'Yes';
echo $this->Html->link($anwer, array('controller' => 'enquiries', 'action' => 'toggle_status', $enquiry['Enquiry']['id']), array('escape' => false));

//OR
$current_enquiry = ($enquiry['Enquiry']['read'] == 0) ? false : true;
echo $this->Html->link($this->Layout->boolYesNo($current), array('controller' => 'enquiries', 'action' => 'toggle_status', $enquiry['Enquiry']['id']), array('escape' => false));
// it does say boolYesNo, so my guess is that it's expecting a bool (not int)
```